# Compare two date fields using Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, comparison, enterprise-library

I want to compare two date fields that the value in one fields should not be greater than the other. Is there a built-in validator for this? Or if I have to write a custom one could you please guide me to a good article to explain how to write custom validators.

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried it with a date, but the [Property Comparison Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664689%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) should work for what you are trying to do.